# How to limit a request to POST in Catalyst

Tags: perl, catalyst

I'm very new to Catalyst and just starting building up a web app to learn some stuff.

One thing that I haven't figured out is how to limit the requests to a given controller method to POST (for instance).

A concrete example would be, the request that will trigger the creation of an object in the Database. Since I want this app to be pretty strict regarding REST verbs, this should only be possible via POST.

I know that I can use 
    $c->method
to check the method used in the request, and return an error or something like that if I don't find what I'm looking for, but I was hoping there was a... cleaner way.

Right now I have something like

```
sub create :Local :Args(0) {
    ...
}
```

Am I doomed to check the method inside the subroutine, and do this for every method there is?

Please do keep in mind that I'm extremely new to Catalyst, so this might be a stupid question.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Catalyst::Controller::REST](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3a%3aController%3a%3aREST) module.

```
sub thing : Local : ActionClass('REST') { }

# Answer POST requests to "thing"
sub thing_POST {
   my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

   # Return a 200 OK, with the data in entity
   # serialized in the body
   $self->status_ok(
        $c,
        entity => {
            some => 'data',
            foo  => 'is real bar-y',
        },
   );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $c->req->method eq 'POST' ) {
    $form->process( params => $c->req->params );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catalyst has had HTTP method matching in core for nearly a year:

http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2013/3

There's pros and cons to using it over Catalyst::Action::REST.  Mostly it comes down to style and also CAR does a better job setting the HTTP accepts header (might be important to you for hard core REST apps)

But for the basics what you get out of the box is fine.